# How does array#shift work? (or any destructive method)

Tags: ruby

I'd like to emulate how array#shift works in ruby, but on a string. Basically, I want to reopen String and add a method that will destructively change the string and return the character that it deletes:

```
class String
  def shift
    char = self[0]
    # I thought this would work... not so fast!
    self = self[1..-1]
    char
  end
end
```

It makes total sense that you can't change the value of self, but then how does array#shift do it? It doesn't even look like the array you're referencing as `self` points to a different object in memory

```
array = [1,2,3]
array.object_id #=> 70215380977180
array.shift
array = [2,3]
array.object_id #=> 70215380977180.. da fuq
```

How does this work?

Comment: You can use `String#replace` to modify self when self is a string.

Comment: And use [Array#replace](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-replace) when `self` is an array, [Hash#replace](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-replace) when it's a hash, [Set#replace](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-replace) for sets and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array#shift!` is [implemented in C](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L1000-L1029), and can operate on the underlying array storage directly.

You can emulate this with `String#slice!`:

```
> str = "foobar"
 => "foobar"
> str.slice!(0, 1)
 => "f"
> str
 => "oobar"
```

If you want to implement this on String:

```
class String
  def shift(n = 1)
    slice!(0, n)
  end
end
```

Comment: Very helpful explanations guys. Looking at how it's implemented in C helps clarify how it's operating directly on array storage. Awesome!